# MP3 metadata is not getting updated

Tags: java, mp3

I want to add album name to mp3 files. I am using [Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger) library for reading and writing mp3 metadata. In my mp3 file there is not media metadata except length. I have attached a screenshot of windows file properties of 1 such mp3 file.
[image]

Given a directory the code goes through all mp3 files inside it and assigns album name to each mp3 file. The code executes without any errors but when I try to open the properties of that mp3 file. Still it does not have any album information. Please help me find out what am I missing.

Below is my code

```
public class Test {

    public static String albumName = null;

    public static String toCamelCase(final String strInput) {
        if (strInput==null)
            return null;
        final String init = strInput.replaceAll("-", " ").replaceAll("_", " ");
        final StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(init.length());

        for (final String word : init.split(" ")) {
            if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                ret.append(word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
                ret.append(word.substring(1).toLowerCase());
            }
            if (!(ret.length()==init.length()))
                ret.append(" ");
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }

    private String getFileExtension(String fileName) {
        String extension = "";
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        int p = Math.max(fileName.lastIndexOf('/'), fileName.lastIndexOf('\\'));

        if (i > p) {
            extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
        }
        return extension;
    }

    private void traverse(File dir) throws CannotReadException, TagException, ReadOnlyFileException, InvalidAudioFrameException, CannotWriteException {
        try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                boolean fileAlbumChecked = false;

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    if (Test.albumName == null)
                        Test.albumName = toCamelCase(file.getName());
                    System.out.println("directory:" + toCamelCase(file.getName()));
                    file.renameTo(new File(file.getCanonicalPath()+"/"+toCamelCase(file.getName())));
                    traverse(file);
                } else {
                    if (getFileExtension(file.getName()).equals("mp3")) {
                        MP3File mp3File  = (MP3File)AudioFileIO.read(file);
                        //MP3AudioHeader audioHeader = (MP3AudioHeader) mp3File.getAudioHeader();
                        boolean hasV1Tag = mp3File.hasID3v1Tag();
                        boolean hasV2Tag = mp3File.hasID3v2Tag();
                        System.out.println(hasV1Tag+", "+hasV2Tag);
                        Tag tag = mp3File.getTag();
                        //ID3v1Tag v1Tag = (ID3v1Tag)tag;
                        AbstractID3v2Tag v2Tag  = mp3File.getID3v2Tag();
                        ID3v24Tag v24Tag = mp3File.getID3v2TagAsv24();
                        String tempAlbumName = null;

                        AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
                        Tag tagwa = audioFile.getTag();
                        System.out.println("("+tagwa+")");
                        if (hasV1Tag) {
                            //Tag tag = mp3File.getTag();
                            //ID3v1Tag v1Tag = (ID3v1Tag)tag;
                            tempAlbumName = (tag.toString());
                            if (Test.albumName == null || Test.albumName.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown") || tempAlbumName != null) {
                                fileAlbumChecked = true;
                                Test.albumName = tempAlbumName;
                                tagwa.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, Test.albumName);
                                audioFile.commit();
                            }
                        } else if (hasV2Tag) {
                            tempAlbumName = (v2Tag.getFirst(ID3v24Frames.FRAME_ID_ALBUM));
                            if (Test.albumName == null || Test.albumName.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown") || tempAlbumName != null) {
                                fileAlbumChecked = true;
                                Test.albumName = tempAlbumName;
                                tagwa.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, Test.albumName);
                                audioFile.commit();
                            }   
                        } else {
                            if (tagwa == null) {
                                tagwa = audioFile.createDefaultTag();
                                System.out.println("("+tagwa+")"+", Class: "+tagwa.getClass());
                            }
                            tagwa.addField(FieldKey.ALBUM, Test.albumName);
                            //tagwa.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, Test.albumName);
                            audioFile.commit();
                        }                       
                        //AudioFileIO.write(audioFile);
                    }                   
                    System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath()+", Album: "+Test.albumName);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String filePath = "C:\\music";
        File dir = new File(filePath);
        Test test = new Test();
        try {
            test.traverse(dir);
        } catch (CannotReadException | TagException | ReadOnlyFileException | InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CannotWriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output

```
directory:Ddlj
false, false
(null)
(Tag content:
), Class: class org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v23Tag
file:C:\music\DDLJ\DDLJ-HO_GAYA_HAI_TUJKO_PYAR_SAJNA.mp3, Album: Ddlj
false, false
(null)
(Tag content:
), Class: class org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v23Tag
file:C:\music\DDLJ\DDLJ-TUJHE_DEKHA_TO.mp3, Album: Ddlj
false, false
(null)
(Tag content:
), Class: class org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v23Tag
file:C:\music\DDLJ\DDLJ-ZARA_SA_JHOOM_LOON_MAIN.mp3, Album: Ddlj
```

Tracing `audioFile.commit()`

on debugging `audioFile.commit();` on line number 103 it does the following code

```
if (id3v2tag == null)
{
    rfile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    (new ID3v24Tag()).delete(rfile);
    (new ID3v23Tag()).delete(rfile);
    (new ID3v22Tag()).delete(rfile);
    logger.config("Deleting ID3v2 tag:"+file.getName());
    rfile.close(); //<-- comes till here
}
...
 rfile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
...
if (TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().isId3v1Save())
{
    logger.config("Processing ID3v1");
    if (id3v1tag == null)
    {
        logger.config("Deleting ID3v1");
        (new ID3v1Tag()).delete(rfile); //<-- comes till here too
    }
    ...
}
... //some catch statements
finally
{
    if (rfile != null)
    {
        rfile.close(); //<-- comes till here too
    }
}
```

and it comes out properly without any errors.

Note: using `jaudiotagger-2.2.4`

Comment: I wonder what kind of Tag is being returned by `audioFile.createDefaultTag()`? Maybe it's not an ID3 tag for some reason, and you need to create it yourself? Try printing out more details about what's happening at important steps so you can see what might be going awry. Even better, step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @tyrel: Thank you for looking into this problem. `audioFile.createDefaulTag()` returns `Tag content: `. I also updated my code with some system outputs and included the result. Please have a look. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Can you also print out (or look when stepping in the debugger) what class the Tag is that's returned? `Tag` is just an interface so I'm wondering if the implementation that's being chosen by default is the correct one.

Comment: @tyrel: it's `org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v23Tag`. Updated my code.

Comment: Okay, that's good to see. Have you tried stepping in to `commit` to see what it's doing? Maybe there is a bug in the library.

Comment: @tyrel: I traced `commit()` it comes out properly. Update my question with debugging of `commit()` inside `org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.class`

Comment: So you have an `ID3v23Tag`, then why is the `commit` code finding `id3v2tag == null` and deleting it? Shouldn't it be adding it?

Answer (score 0):

The following code reads an existing ALBUM tag from an MP3 file, and then overwrites it with a new ALBUM tag.

```
MP3File audioFile = (MP3File) AudioFileIO.read(new File("test.mp3"));
Tag tag = audioFile.getTag();
if (tag == null) {
    tag = new ID3v22Tag();
}
List<TagField> albumFields = tag.getFields(FieldKey.ALBUM);
System.out.println("Existing ALBUM fields: " + albumFields);
tag.deleteField(FieldKey.ALBUM);
tag.addField(FieldKey.ALBUM, "test album 2");
audioFile.setTag(tag);
audioFile.save();
```

It has been tested to work with java 1.7 and jaudiotagger 2.2.3 on Linux.